Remark in Atiyah, Macdonald: non-singularity $\Rightarrow$ analytic irreducibility
In Atiyah, Macdonald, Introduction to Commutative Algebra, Chapter 11, p. 124, after Proposition 11.24, there is a

Remark. It follows from what we have said above that A is also an integral
domain. Geometrically speaking this means that (locally)
non-singularity $\Rightarrow$ analytic irreducibility
or that, at a non-singular point, there is only one analytic “branch”.

Can someone expand on the meaning of these words? What is analytic irreducibility? What is it meant by analytic “branch”?

The $\operatorname{Spec}$ of a reduced ring $A$ is irreducible if and only if $A$ is an integral domain. But even then it can happen that the completion $\hat A$ at a maximal ideal is not an integral domain. One says $A$ is analytically irreducible at a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ if the completion $\hat A$ is integral. The minimal prime ideals of $\hat A$ are called analytic branches. Note that a (localisation of a) finitely generated $k$-algebra is regular if and only if $\hat A$ is isomorphic to a power series ring $\hat A \cong k[[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]]$, which is always an integral domain.
For an example, consider
$$A = \mathbb C[x,y] / (y^2 - x^2(x+1)).$$
$\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is a curve with one nodal singularity. It's completion is
$$\hat A = \mathbb C[[x,y]] / (y^2-x^2(x+1)).$$
In $\mathbb C[[x,y]]$ we have a square root
$$\sqrt{1+x} = (1+x)^{\frac 1 2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\frac 1 2}{k}x^k = 1 + \frac x 2 - \frac{x^2}8 + \dotsc$$
Thus $\hat A$ is not an integral domain, since
$$y^2 - x^2(x+1) = (y-x \sqrt{1+x})(y+x\sqrt{1+x}).$$
Since $\sqrt{1+x}$ is a unit in $\mathbb C[[x,y]]$, setting $\tilde x = x \sqrt{1+x}$ we even see that
$$\hat A = \mathbb C[[\tilde x, y]] / ((y-\tilde x)(y+\tilde x)).$$
So ring-theoretically you cannot distinguish $\hat A$ from the completion of $\mathbb C[x,y]/((x+y)(x-y))$, which is the ring corresponding to the intersection of two lines.
We say $A$ has two analytic branches at $(x,y)$, corresponding to the minimal prime ideals of $\hat A$, hence it is not analytically irreducible.
I always find it helpful to consider the geometry. Here is an image of $y^2 = x^2(x+1)$:

